# Return null in aggregate column if where clause returns nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, case, where-clause

I have this query in MsSQL

```
SELECT PersonnelID, Name, EmpStartCalc,
    MAX(PositionDetailsValidFromCalc) PD , 
    Max(PositionHierValidFromCalc) PH, 
    Max(PWAValidFromCalc) Position, 
    Max(RowId) As RowId
    
FROM TV_IAMintegration_VW
    
where 
    EmpStartCalc >= 20200101 and
    EmpStartCalc <= 20200131 and
    
    ((20200131 > PositionDetailsValidFromCalc And 
    20200101 < PositionDetailsValidToCalc) or
    PositionDetailsValidToCalc is null)
    
GROUP BY PersonnelID, Name, EmpStartCalc
    
ORDER BY PersonnelID Asc.
```

I have a scenario where I need the query to return Null, example:

When where clause doesn't successfully meet I need the query to return null in the following columns

```
MAX(PositionDetailsValidFromCalc) PD , Max(PositionHierValidFromCalc) PH, Max(PWAValidFromCalc) Position
```

but rest of the row remains same.

Comment: The answer in the other post is inefficient. I have a better answer with conditional aggregation, please reopen. The question here is also much clearer than there

Comment: Totally agreed, this question is different than the mentioned duplicate.

Comment: If you edit the post to explain that, you may get it reopened

Comment: Already did, waiting for the moderator to take some action.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use a CTE:

```
with cte as (
      your query here
     )
select cte.*
from cte
union all
select null, null, null, null, null, null
from (values (1)) v(x)
where not exists (select 1 from cte);
```